# Putting landing page made with nextjs on wordpress website

Tags: front-end

I made a one landing page website with nextjs locally, and I already have an online wordpress website with nothing on it, I need to put that page on it in a way that I could be able after that to manage the page content through wordpress.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: There is, probably dozens of different ways to do this.  Your question is really broad and open ended and really all you've asked is "Can this be done?" Yes it can.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to rewrite the page in PHP using shortcodes or meta boxes. Or you could build the page with Gutenberg blocks.